# Cheapest way to limit 4xAA to 5v or less

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, battery-operated

I need to limit the voltage from AA batteries to 5.25V or less. Essentially, my circuit can operate from (minimum) 3.5V up to 5.25V, and I want to maximize run time by using 4xAA. Should I just run it off 3xAA batteries (giving 4.5V when full) or is there a way this can be done (without the expense of a switching regulator)? I have read that using zener diodes is not great since it wastes power and limits current, which is critical (I need to draw around 1.5A from the batteries).

EDIT:
Sounds like a boost converter with 2S2P batteries will be best. For reverse polarity protection, should I just include a regular diode in series? Wouldn't that lose 0.7v?

Comment: MOSFET LDO's are the best solution as BiPolar LDO's drop too much voltage.  but knowing the mAh of the batteries, you can estimate how short the lifespan will be.

Comment: Anyone trying to sustain 1.5A from AA cells will be buying a lot of batteries.  good Eng design matches the battery to the load using high efficiency.

Comment: 1.5A is only being drawn about 5% of the time, the remaining 95% of the time usage will be closer to 0.2A. I've estimated a run-time of 11 hours assuming I can suck all 2500mAh out of the batteries.

Comment: 2S2P should work well for this if need to use regular AAs :)

You could use a P-channel fet to minimise forward voltage drop, many boost circuits use a p-channel fet in design so may essentially include some kind of reverse polarity. I would need to pull one of those boards out my drawers to test but I cant see one near me and not near a DMM right now, sorry :-s

Comment: These may be even more suited, given your low average draw, only 40 cents each :-O - https://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-Electronics-2-24V-to-2-28V-2A-DC-DC-SX1308-Step-UP-Power-Module-Boost/192292790446?hash=item2cc58b20ae:g:dCsAAOSwX99Zpn8A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it? Is cost THAT much of an issue?

Using a zener will work, but to work well with such a large load, 1.5A, your going to waste people's batteries IMO, and to be fair 1.5A is not trivial for AA batteries, though good alkaline batteries will be OK.

A  linear regulator will burn excess voltage as heat, so if you don't wish to waste power, then its not a great option, but better then a zener IMO.

1.5A is way too much for a typical joule thief I would think, but the idea is OK so...

So I am afraid the best option IS a switching reg, you can have 3A units off ebay for like a dollar, or even less.

For something that will cope with the low voltage I would suggest adapting the AA supply to 2 sets of 2xAA in parallel, to provide 3V. If you do this you can get away with just a boost circuit (to save cost over a buck/boost), and  will reduce the current draw on each AA - enabling better runtime and using the boost converter to draw every last drop out of the batteries. If you set the boost to somewhere near your circuit minimum (3.5V as you suggest), then the boost will be working at the highest possible efficiency (close to the 2-3V VCC from your AAs in parallel), and potentially reducing losses elsewhere in your circuit.

If you're willing to risk a dollar, you would get much more use out of the batteries and have a better item with the latter option (boost conv) - think of the environment ;-)

Comment: +1 also wondering in the OP has taken battery reversal into account....

Comment: Yes please consider what Trevor said... As for suitable example of a boost thats suitable for 1.5A load, only 1 dollar Canadian  - https://www.ebay.com/itm/Blue-Wandler-MT3608-2A-Max-DC-DC-Step-Up-Power-Module-Boost-Power-For-Arduino-CN/232433601767?hash=item361e1f4ce7:g:zZ4AAOSwaWNZgnul

Comment: With OP updated description, another option is this (only 40 cents each) - https://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-Electronics-2-24V-to-2-28V-2A-DC-DC-SX1308-Step-UP-Power-Module-Boost/192292790446?hash=item2cc58b20ae:g:dCsAAOSwX99Zpn8A

Answer (score 0):

The really inexpensive 5V USB power supply that I purchased many years ago was simply 4- "AA" cells in a battery holder with a couple of 5.1V 1 Watt Zener Diodes soldered right across the battery terminals.

Fresh cells discharged very quickly down to just below the Zener voltage and then stayed at that voltage for many months.

Completely cheesy but it did work. I still use that supply to this day.

Comment: Interesting. Cost really is the primary concern here (will be selling these at a craft show) so if I can just do that, that would be perfect! Sounds like this might be the way to go.

Comment: @ErikJohnson  UM... if this is for sale, you had better test that with a variety of battery types. It might be ok with alkalines, but not others.

Comment: 4AA cells would discharge to about 5/4 ~= 1.25V. That might waste about half their capacity! Talk about crappy design...

Answer (score 0):

You could run your application on only 3*AA 1.5 V cells, but I'd suggest you need to use Li primary cells.

Any other solution will introduce losses and you can use almost all the energy in the battery by just using 3 batteries.

Here's a datasheet for a [AA](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf) Alkaline ...which I would not recommend you use.

Notice here that the current you want to draw is way outside the battery capability. This will severely reduce the capacity you can access and using 4 with a buck regulator will still not get you into it's current rating.

If you use [Lithium primary AA cells](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf), these have a no load voltage of about 1.8V, so with new batteries you have to ensure your application can sustain the voltage (5.4 V) when not operating. As soon as you load the battery the voltage drops about 100 mV so brings you well within spec.

The datasheet shows a comparison of Alkaline vs Li as below:

[image]

Comment: I agree that the lithium is more suited to the application - OP states cost conscious so hence not wishing to suggest batteries that may cost more than what this is is worth... Splitting the current between AA batts (rechargables would work better) should help I would think but by your graph even 750mA is large - batts vary tho, op has come testing to do: https://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm     -     

Depending upon what this is if one was to use a boost with rechargables may be cheaper than lithium AND suited to load? From experiance the boost will drop out completely around 1.6-1.8V.